# Can you marry a girl in Stardew Valley if you are a girl?

Tags: stardew-valley

Can you marry a girl in Stardew Valley if you are a girl? My character is a girl and I just wanted to know if you can marry a woman.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Yes you can. All the bachelors/bachelorettes are available for everyone, regardless of the sex of your character

Comment: If you are a female and date Leah her ex will be female too.

Comment: All couples can have kids, too - it makes a few references to adoption for same-sex couples, but the in-game mechanism is the same. (I.e. babies show up magically overnight.)

Comment: Comments were deleted. This is not the place to discuss the frequency of various sexualities.

Comment: This page contains a list of all people who can be romanced: https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Marriage

Comment: @Parrotmaster amusingly, it's cheaper to erase memories from a past marriage than to get divorced.